# e2fsck aborts even though filesystem is unmounted

Tags: 20.04, fsck

I am using a live Ubuntu USB disk (20.04) to repair a filesystem on another USB disk. The e2fsck command aborts because the filesystem is perceived as "in use".

- The filesystem is unmounted, and this is confirmed when I use the umount command.
- I run fuser to identify any processes using the unmounted filesystem.
- Fuser identifies 3 processes using the filesystem: cupsd, rsyslogd and unattended-upgrade...
- I try killing the processes but cupsd and rsyslogd simply restart.
- Afterwards, e2fsck still aborts
- If I reboot, the problem replicates itself.

You can see the code I've used and the results below. How can I repair this filesystem?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo umount /dev/sdb5
umount: /dev/sdb5: not mounted.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo e2fsck -p /dev/sdb5
/dev/sdb5 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fuser -m /dev/sdb5
/dev/sdb5:            1584  1590  1722
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ps -p 1584
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
   1584 ?        00:00:00 rsyslogd
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ps -p 1590
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
   1590 ?        00:00:00 cupsd
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ps -p 1722
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
   1722 ?        00:00:00 unattended-upgr
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it happens after cloning a drive with `dd`. So  I believe e2fsck is using only the UUID for its mount check (and the UUID is not unique anymore as `dd` clones it)

Comment: I am not using any cloned disks in my scenario, so this doesn't explain my problem. Thanks anyway @eddygeek